# How can I tell Gradle to pick a given native library from only a specific aar

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to build an app that relies on dependencies which pull in numerous versions of libc++_shared.so; the usual

```
packagingOptions {
  pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
  pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
}
```

dance allows the build to succeed, but I have a runtime crash because some of the libc++_shared versions (apparently including the one Gradle sees first and picks) were compiled without exception handling support, and other dependencies require native exception handling. I believe this to be the case because I kept seeing java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__sfp_handle_exceptions" crashes at runtime when the native lib that requires exception handling was loaded.

I'm the author of one of the aars and I know its libc++_shared has exception handling, so I'm trying to force Gradle to specifically choose libc++_shared from that known aar.  I tried the following after seeing that the cached version of the aar I want to draw from has libc++_shared under jni/abi/

```
exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
pickFirst 'com/mycompany/*/jni/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
pickFirst 'com/mycompany/*/jni/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
```

and also

```
exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
pickFirst 'com.mycompany/*/jni/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
pickFirst 'com.mycompany/*/jni/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
```

as well as the two permutations above with the aar module name mymodule-1.1.1 in place of the wildcard.  Unfortunately, these have all led to no version of libc++_shared.so being included in the final apk, so I'm guessing I either have the wrong aar path syntax or pickFirst can't be used for this purpose.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to get a list of file paths Gradle is considering for packaging so I don't have to guess at what the aar name and structure will be by the time Gradle's packagingOptions is looking at it?
2. How can I tell Gradle to package only a specific libc++_shared from a given aar?

EDIT: Not a general solution, but I found a workaround to this specific case -- the problem first arose when I enabled transitive dependencies in my com.mycompany:mainsdk dependency, and the native modules that package an exception handling libc++_shared thus became only transitive; previously I had been pulling down all com.mycompany modules directly as their pom files didn't have transitive dep info, but after adding that info I figured I would only need the single com.mycompany:mainsdk dependency.  This supposition was nominally true, but apparently had the side-effect of making the libc++_shared version packaged with com.mycompany native deps either show up later in the Gradle packaging sequence or be considered lower priority such that another direct dependency that packaged libc++_shared without exception handling was always selected by pickFirst.  I tried bringing back one of the com.mycompany native dep modules as a direct dep and suddenly Gradle always picks libc++_shared from him!  Dunno if it's important, but the native dep I added back appears before the one that was pulling in libc++_shared without exception handling.  Good ol' Gradle mysteries...

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Comment: @Rookie not beyond the workaround I added at the end; by directly naming my dependency with the correct libc++_shared lib version and putting it earlier in the dependencies list than the problematic one I always got the correct libc++_shared. That was good enough, so I gladly stopped looking into Gradle mechanics!